# Bluetooth connection works but Preferences shows not connected

Tags: 11.10, unity, bluetooth

My Nokia N810 is Bluetooth paired with Ubuntu desktop and successfully transfers files.

The Ubuntu Bluetooth indicator shows the N810. When I bring up Bluetooth Preferences it shows desktop Bluetooth on and visible but when selecting any paired device it's shown as connection off and won't let be slide the switch to on.

I'm aware that Bluetooth devices only connect with one paired partner at a time and insured that's not the issue. I've also paired with a Bluetooth GPS receiver which displays the same the same Preferences issue.

I know it works with my my N810 but have been unable to get FoxtrorGPS on Ubuntu to use the GPS and can't determine if it works with Ubuntu even if Preferences refuses to see the connection in any fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like some have had an issue after an update for Ubuntu 11.10.

Just had to install blueman like this:

You can add blueman repositories by issuing this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blueman/ppa
```

And to install it run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

also check this:

Go into Terminal and type this:

```
gksu nautilus /etc/xdg/autostart
```